# Server won't respond to customer - Wordpress site / Hostgator - high volume

Tags: wordpress, server, cpanel, hostgator

I've got a customer using WordPress. They have been using it for years. It's a school where the kids get on each day and hit the site A LOT.

Suddenly, in the last 3 days they get NOTHING back from the server (this ONLY occurs from within the school).

If we do a `tracert`, we get out and seemingly get to the server.

But if I look at network traffic on Chrome -- I never receive a response.  This same thing happens on IE and FF.

A look at CPanel shows that no IPs are being blocked.  I've never done IP blocking so am not sure if this is what one who is blocked would even expect to see.

We are a reseller for Hostgator... I wonder if something higher up the chain (maybe on their end) is causing this. I've got a ticket in with them.

THIS JUST IN: I found out that the customer can reach the site when they skip their firewall... this leads me to believe that it HAS to be their firewall (even if their firewall provider says it's not).

Comment: Swallow your pride and contact hostgator.. that's what your paying them for.

Comment: I've got a ticket in with them...waiting.  In the meantime, I found out that the customer can reach the site when they skip their Firewall... this leads me to believe that it HAS to be their Firewall (even if their firewall company says its not) :)

Comment: If you have your own answer, answer the question using ADD answer... that way we can move onto more unanswereds :P

Answer (score 1):

**First, restart the router.**

This sounds like it may be a DNS issue and not with the site itself. Try accessing the IP address of the site rather than the URL (e.g., instead of `http://google.com`, type `http://12.345.67.891`). If it works, it's probably a DNS resolution problem. To fix, open up command prompt and run `ipconfig /flushdns`

Comment: If it was a DNS problem, would it still follow the tracert?

Comment: Tracert wouldn't work if it was related to DNS (if the end ip is correct).